# Facebook Javascript API Takes A Long Time to Initialize when There Are A Lot of Images on The Page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web, initialization, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I recently ran into an issue where Facebook API takes a very long time to initialize when there are a lot of images on the page. I would this is more visible when there are about 50MB of images. Facebook init is actually called first before everything, but it still seems to wait until all images are loaded first. 95% of images are actually appended to the page asynchronously.

Has anyone run into a similar issue? At this point, I'm not sure if it's a bug or how browsers behave, but it's pretty consistent across Chrome and Safari. I have also made sure that there is no synchronous code anywhere that could have blocked the initialization.

Since we rely on Facebook to figure out if user has already logged in by first checking the cookie (or make a call to Facebook if no cookie), this is affecting user's experience quite a bit. We are also using Facebook login as primary way so user is not able to login until the API is initialized.

This is very easily reproducible with slower internet connection. If you want to see the actual behavior, you can go to https://www.toovia.com. Click on login on top right and you will see that Face Pile isn't there i.e. the API is still being initialized.

Here's how I'm initializing the API. It's pretty much copied from Facebook documentation.

```
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI. We ended up solving the issue with 3 steps.

1. We implemented image resizing scheme so the pages now load about
   10x faster.
2. Append the fb element as close to the top as
   possible.
3. Implemented a wrapper for Facebook class to handle all
   dependent classes of FB class so that they can be initialized
   without having to wait for FB. They are then invoked when FB object
   is ready to execute whatever logic that is left.

Our code is rather complex so by having the fb element at the top only without extra steps simply causes too many unexpected issues due to timing. It's also has a lot of performance impact if everything has to wait for FB object to be initialized even though only subset of the logic depends on FB.

Comment: Can you please add some code samples for each of the above 3 points? I am facing the exact same problem with my website as well. If you have a blog or something where I can follow this, it would be great too. BTW, you can even ask FB to include your fixes/recommendations on their own API page as well as I think every FB API user might need those.

Answer (score 0):

Use the async version of the sdk init and do all your api calls from with in it where the comments ays make all graph api calls here.

The calls will not be made until the sdk has loaded completely.

refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#asynchronous

---

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });
// do all function calls or class calls here as well, fb related.
    // make all graph api calls here
    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: Just FYI. This is what I'm already doing. There is no API call until after it's initialized. The problem is that it takes way too long to initialize to the point that when user is trying to take a manual action 10+ seconds later, it's still not initialized.